# Automate logon to https site

Tags: .net, https

My new ISP requires me to login for each session of internet usage. After a session gets timed out, it redirects to the provider website (https), where I have to enter the username and password.
Since it logs out and terminates session I cannot schedule downloads during night.
I was thinking of some way to automate this, probably write a .net service which does this?

Any idea on this would be helpful.

(If I close the browser and clear the history, I get logged out.)

Comment: Is your isp using form based or basic authentication?

Answer (score 0):

The is a firefox extension called ReloadEvery, which allows you to specify how often you would like a page to be automatically reloaded.

This would prevent your session from timing out due to inactivity.